# Sublime Text with multiple windows: How to always open the same file in the same window?

Tags: sublimetext3

Here is my ST3 setup:

I have one window with a set of tabs that I use to editing the source. 
I have another window with a set of tabs that I use to work with the resulting logs.

The problem I have is that if I close a log file tab, make changes to the source and then re-open the log file I closed, the tab opens in the source window, because the source window last had focus.

Is there a way of making Sublime Text remember the window that the file was last active in and therefore re-opening the file in the same window?

UPDATE:
I should note that I'm on Windows.

Also, to explain further:
Here is the setup (Window1 and Window2 are both Sublime Text Windows):

```
Window1: file1.cpp, file2.cpp, file2.h
Window2: app.log, server.log <- this window has focus while I look at the log
```

Now, I close app.log and make some changes to a cpp file. Here is the picture now

```
Window1: file1.cpp, file2.cpp, file2.h <- this window has focus now
Window2: server.log
```

Next, I compile and run my app. app.log gets modified. I double-click it.
Here's the new state:

```
Window1: file1.cpp, file2.cpp, file2.h, app.log <- this window has focus
Window2: server.log
```

What I want to happen instead is:

```
Window1: file1.cpp, file2.cpp, file2.h (doesn't matter which window has focus)
Window2: server.log, app.log (app.log is back in Window2, where it was when I last closed it)
```

Is this possible at all on ST3? Being possible on ST3 on Windows would be ideal.

Answer (score 20):

on mac goto the sublime text > preferences > settings-default 
then find on line 301 usually this line
    "open_files_in_new_window": false,
make sure its false, it might be set to true

Comment: Yes, good answer. But how do you get the same behavior when you launch ST3 with the common command line `subl` alias? ... I want all files launched in same window when opening from CLI. Any help out there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try the `-a` parameter to the subl alias.  Also check out `subl --help`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu too, you can do the same.

Here are the shortcuts

```
shift+alt+1 - 1 colomn
shift+alt+2 - 2 colomn 
shift+alt+3 - 3 colomn
shift+alt+4 - 4 colomn
shift+alt+5 - 4 GRID
```

and so on

Comment: No, that's not the same because that just re-arranges the tabs in a single window. I use two windows, each with their own set of tabs. I don't want more than a single column layout because then the screen real estate decreases.